# How to trim spaces in xml tags using regular expression in notepad++?

Tags: xml, regex, xml-parsing, notepad++

I am trying to trim a space in an `XML` tag, this is an example of what I have:

```
<xmlT ag>
content between tag
</xmlTa g>
```

to:

```
<xmlTag>
content between tag
</xmlTag>
```

This is the expression that I wrote for that:

Find: `[<](\w)* (\w)*[>]|[<][/](\w)* (\w)*[>]`
Replace: `\1\2`

but is not working as expected.
Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Replace `<xmlT ag>` with `<xmlTag>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tags only have one space in them and no attributes, this will work

find: `<(/?)(\w*) (\w*)>`

replace: `<\1\2\3>`

Answer (score 2):

Using a LookAhead we can repair any number of spaces in a tag:

Search for: `\s+(?=[\s\w]*>)`
Replace with nothing

Explained demo here: http://www.regex101.com/r/dY6zC2

*Note: LookAhead is available in NotePad++ since version 6.0*

Comment: There is no lookahead in notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ supports PCRE including look-aheads and look-behinds (since v6.0).

Comment: @btoueg actually just tested on Notepad++ 6.3.1 and it supports LookAhead and works flawlessly.

Comment: @MikeM thanks for clarifying, also Notepad++ 6.3 was available at the time the question was posted

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. It looks like I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited.