# How to trim any number of spaces in xml tags using a regular expression in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to trim a space in an XML tag, this is an example of what I have:

```
<xmlT ag>
content between tag
</xmlTa g>
```

to:

```
<xmlTag>
content between tag
</xmlTag>
```

(This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342915/how-to-trim-spaces-in-xml-tags-using-regular-expression-in-notepad) for Notepad++ but including a solution for vim that isn't obvious.)

Note: The solution should handle multiple spaces as well, such as:

```
<messed up t ag>
```

which would become

```
<messseduptag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344878/1905648) provided for Notepad++ includes the use of the notation `[\s\w]` which is [not supported](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4505) in vim.

With a combination of both answers, plus an understanding of how to perform [positive lookahead in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391881/1905648), you can use this expression in vim to strip any amount of whitespace within xml tags:

```
:%s/\s\+\([[:space:][:alnum:]_]*>\)\@=//gc
```

**Explanation:**

We are looking for whitespace (`\s`) one or more times (`+`), that **also has in front of it** (`\@=`) a space or an alphanumeric character or an underscore (`\([[:space:][:alnum:]_]*>\)`) zero or more times (`*`) followed by a `>`. We will replace the one or more whitespace characters (that is, the `\s\+` from the start of the expression) with nothing (`//`) throughout the entire file (`g`) and ask for confirmation (`c`) before anything is is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple substitute command works for the first example:

```
%s/\(<\/*xml\w\+\)\s\+/\1/g
```

A more general substitution will remove any number of spaces from an arbitrary XML tag

```
:%s/<\zs.*\ze>/\=substitute(submatch(0),' ','','g')
```

Comment: This will only work specifically with ```<xml something>``` which was only an example.  I want it to work with ```<Some Messed Up Tag>``` as well as ```<Some Tag>``` so it must support more than one space as well.